# Search in PDF for error in Dimensions and highlight the error

Tags: python, highlight

I need a help in writing a python program for (find dimensions like 12 In. (304.8 mm) in whole multiple PDFs and should highlight the wrong existance of conversions shown in the PDFs) Also need which page the error in conversion happened or highlight the error

```
import PyPDF4
import re

FILE_PATH = 'C:\HB on Installation & Maintenance practices of EPM 220 mm.pdf'
with open(FILE_PATH, mode='rb') as f:
    reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(f)
    page = reader.getPage(4)
    txt = page.extractText()

    location = re.findall("220 mm", txt)
    print(location)
```

Comment: How far have you progressed in solving this problem?

Comment: Use [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) instead of PyPDF2/PyPDF3/PyPDF4. I am the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. We improved pypdf a lot in 2022.